# How can I make SQL automatically copy certain rows in a table to another table in the same Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The source table has a fixed number of rows that get updated at various random intervals. My intent is to create a second table to store the historical data. i.e: Whenever a row gets updated in the original table, a new row has to be automatically added to the secondary table. The speed of this "copying" operation is not crutial, it is fine if this "copying" operation took some seconds to cach up.

How many methods are there to automatically perform this inside SQL? preferably without using 3rd party applications?

Is there a difference between adding new rows from an external source and "copying" rows from one table to another within the same database in terms of Computer resources utilization? i.e: if a certain PC is capable of writing X rows per second to a table in SQL, can this PC "copy" the same X number of rows between tables in the same database?

What is the reliability of the solution that copies rows between tables? is there a possibility to lose some data in the copying process? (for example, a row in the original table gets updated, then updated again before the "copying" operation had the time to finish the copying process, what would happen in this situation?)

Comment: This can be done by [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MS SQL, not MySQL. sorry for the confusion, corrected the question tags.

Comment: "whenver a row gets updated" sounds like this could be handled with a TRIGGER, a  
 BEFORE UPDATE trigger.

Comment: have you looked at temporal tables rater than coding your own solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is the exact thing that triggers are for. You need to write a triggers on the original table that accordingly update the secondary table. Trigger functionality exists in all enterprise grade databases.

There is no risk of data loss - trigger fires as part of the same transaction that the original row-modifying query executes, so either both changes stick, or neither change sticks.

Comment: Would triggers be suitble if there were arownd 100 such "original tables", each of which has a peak traffic of  around 100 line entries per second? 
I know that this can be heavily affected by the server's hardware capabilities. Lets say that the server is fairly modern. I realise that this is a general question that can best be answered with actual testing. I am just trying to see if this solution is generally suitable for such applications before actually commiting to the testing.

Comment: If you need such data changes to be automated, I don't see that you have a choice. Triggers are no more expensive than any other way of keeping the tables in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Explore various built-in options such as same old Triggers, Change Data Capture , Change Tracking etc. For the later two you may need DBA involvement.

Onpremise or Cloud , data volume that gets changed, how long you need to keep the history etc should be your parameters in selecting the right approach.